# Not getting max value more than 'D99999' in MySQL from varchar column

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

```
Deposit_number
--------------
D100000
D99999
D50
.....
D4
D3
D2
D1
```

I am trying to get record by using following JPA query deposit

```
Deposit findTopByCompanyOrderByDepositNumberDesc(Company company);
```

But in result I am getting record which containing `'D99999'` and I am expecting 'D100000'. Please help if any one have idea to fix this problem. I want to solve this using a JPA query, not by using a SQL native query.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Deposit_number` column is text, but you are expecting the numbers to sort as numbers, not text.  Assuming the `D` is a constant prefix, and only non numeric character, throughout the column, we can try the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(Deposit_number, 2) AS SIGNED) DESC;
```

Does this query look ugly?  Yes, it does, but then again the way you are storing your deposit numbers is also ugly.  If you don't want to have to use the above query, then consider storing the deposit numbers in a separate column.